# Spring 2.5 Controller Annotations

Tags: spring-mvc

Spring MVC Question. I need to port a Spring 2.5 app to a Spring 2.0 Jboss server. The only Spring 2.5 constructs used are the following Controller Annomations: @Controller, @RequestMapping, @ReqestParm, @ModelAttribute and @Autowired.

I am having difficulty determining which base controllers to extend or implement.

Any thoughts on how to migrate Controllers back to 2.0 from 2.5 would be helpful. Ideally, a before (Spring 2.0) / After (Spring 2.5) example would be great.

I am new to Spring.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For controllers you may want to go back to the Spring 2.0 documentation:
http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/reference/mvc.html#mvc-controller

I would just remove the annotations, that are causing a problem, and then replace them, so @Autowire becomes code in the application.xml file, the controller annotations you just follow the link above.

There isn't a migration so much as just removing the new features and just restoring the old way of doing these tasks.